# How to Deploy production grade Jenkins server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, production-environment

I want to deploy **Jenkins** on **AWS** but I don't know what is the best way to deploy it.
I watched videos and read articles and below are some possible solutions.

1- Jenkins as a docker container, bind the volume and expose it with ELB or Nginx reverse proxy.

2- Jenkins on EKS or unmanaged K8s cluster and expose it via ELB.

3- Install as a regular application via an apt-get command in EC2 and expose it via Nginx reverse/ELB.

I don't know what is the best way to deploy in production.

P.S: next plan is to deploy our **Nexus** and **Sonarqube** servers as well.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Well it completely depends on many factors such as:

1. Cost
2. Number of users (High availability)

If cost isn't a big issue, you can use Amazon EKS cluster to deploy highly available Jenkins server.

Checkout [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/deploying-jenkins-on-amazon-eks-with-amazon-efs/) on how to do it on EKS.